# Python Unix authentication

Tags: python, unix, authentication, pam

I need to do a simple authentication of username's which are on the host and NIS. 
I am writing this code in Python.
I tried using PAM to do authentication. For this I downloaded a Python module called Python Pam. 
The code I use :

```
import pam   
pam.authenticate('root',<password>,<service>)
```

where `<service>` is a config file I created in /etc/pam.d/

the file contains the following code

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth     requisite      pam_unix.so
```

This code works on certain hosts giving the correct answer, but not on others 
Even if I replaced `<service>` with login or sshd as in

```
pam.authenticate('root',<password>,'sshd')
```

It still returns False for a correct password on certain hosts. 
So does anybody know why this does not work. I don't need to use pam or any module. Is there any command in unix that I can invoke from Python which would just authenticate a username? and preferably work across all unix based systems including Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX. 
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to conduct further trials with other usernames? For example, the usual default configuration of sshd won't allow root at all, as a security measure.

Answer (score 1):

Both

```
 pam.authenticate('myusername', 'mypassword', 'sshd')
```

and

```
 pam.authenticate('myusername', 'mypassword')
```

Login works fine on my machine. The documentation for the `pam` module is pretty much non-existent, so if you configured your service correctly or not is hard for me to say.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to that lies in the third parameter in the `/etc/pam.d/` file you created.

Try this command on the machines where it does not work.  Yes, you must be root or sudoer root.

```
# ldconfig -v |grep pam_unix.so
```

Most likely a symlink does not lead to the real pam shared library from `pam_unix.so`.  Add it or change the config file parameter to something that `ld` can use to find the link.